# JSTL c:if statement not working

Tags: html, jsp, jstl

I want to be able to send an alert if a query string exists, but I dont need to know the value it returns, just that it exists.

I tried this, but it doesnt work:

```
<% 
request.setAttribute("appInfo", request.getParameter("appInfo"));
%>
<c:if test="${appInfo}">
<script>
alert("${appInfo}");
</script>
</c:if>
```

I also tried this (with the url being ?appInfo=88) and it worked.

```
<%
request.setAttribute("appInfo", request.getParameter("appInfo"));
%>
<c:if test="${appInfo == 88}">
<script>
alert("${appInfo}");
</script>
</c:if>
```

I dont understand why solution 2 works but 1 doesnt, any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

`c:if` doesn't work like a Javascript if, where non-null values will be regarded as "truthy".  For `c:if` you need a result that actually is true or false.  You can do

```
<c:if test="${appInfo != null}">
```

to check if the value is there.